# Applying lapply on Multiple Data Frames in a List, R

Tags: r

I have a list of similar data frames in a list u (4 columns, all with same headers) and would like to run an lapply function to get the correlation of columns 2 and 3 of each data frame. I want the function to read any integer i (the list has 300+ csvs).

I've tried this code but it hasn't worked:

```
i<-1:2
for (i) lapply(u, cor(u[[i]][,2],u[[i]][,3]))
```

Can someone please help me fix this code? Still fairly new to the program.

Edit: I've tried Metrics code below and it works, unfortunately one of the csvs contain only headers and no data. I get this error: Error in cor(u[, 2], u[, 3]) : 'x' is empty

Is there anyway sapply can be modified so that the "cor" function returns 0 if there isn't any data available?

Comment: just for reference:  `i` in the example above is not an iterator, just a vecotr (a "list") of numbers.  You need something to iterate over them.   eg:  `for (j in i)`  or just `for (j in 1:2)` or  `for (i in 1:2)`

Answer (score 8):

x contains the list of all dataframes. In the following example, I have used two dataframes from R. (mtcars and iris)

```
list(mtcars=mtcars,iris=iris)
lapply(x,function(x)cor(x[,2],x[,3]))
[[1]]
[1] 0.9020329

[[2]]
[1] -0.4284401
```

Or, if you want the vector output:

```
sapply(x,function(x)cor(x[,2],x[,3]))
[1]  0.9020329 -0.4284401
```

Comment: If you give names to your list elements the result will be slightly more readable : `x<-list(mtcars=mtcars,iris=iris)`